# No results behavior in Views PDF does not show

Tags: views

I'm using Views PDF to generate PDFs with exposed filters (looking for a product by product # and brand name). My view has 10 displays because each language uses its own template (configured in row style). I'm placing each field on the page using x and y coordinates.

I've added a Global: Text area "no products found" message to the "No results behavior" - to show when the filter values do not yield any rows. I'm just getting a blank PDF however - no message is shown.

Is the No results behavior not supported in the Views PDF module? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Is it possible that it's returning a seemingly empty value, and therefore the No Results behaviour isn't being triggered?

Comment: No. In that case at least the template would be rendered - which it isn't.

Comment: IS any of the views section being rendered?

Comment: Just a blank PDF, nothing more.